# Easy way to validate the shape of an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, shapes

I’m wondering if there’s a simple way of validating the shape of an object in Javascript.

Right now, I have a function that validates the shape of endpoint objects like this:

```
function validateEndpointShape(endpoint: any, hasId: boolean): boolean 
{
return endpoint
&& (hasId ? typeof endpoint.id === 'string' : true)
&& typeof endpoint.name === 'string'
&& typeof endpoint.description === 'string'
&& typeof endpoint.url === 'string'
&& GenericApiEndpointMethods[endpoint.method] !== undefined
&& ApiEndpointTypes[endpoint.apiEndpointType] !== undefined
&& endpoint.group
&& typeof endpoint.group.groupPublicKey === 'string'
&& typeof endpoint.group.groupName === 'string'
&& typeof endpoint.reason === 'string'
&& typeof endpoint.isPublic === 'boolean'
&& typeof endpoint.isActive === 'boolean'
&& authTypes[endpoint.authType] !== undefined
&& Array.isArray(endpoint.parameters)
&& Array.isArray(endpoint.headers);
}
```

This can get cumbersome and unwieldy. And I don’t want to have to do this for every object I create.

When an endpoint comes into our cloud firebase function, we have to do a bunch of validation on it so that we know when to reject bad data. The shape of the endpoint is one of those validations.

I tried doing this:

```
Delete req.body.reason;
req.body[‘extraField’] = ‘xxx’;
Const endpoint: GenericApiEndpoint = req.body;
console.log(‘endpoint =‘, endpoint);
```

But Javascript doesn’t care. It will accept an endpoint without reason (a mandatory field) and with extraField (a non-existent field in the model) and assign it to an object typed as GenericApiEndpoint. Endpoint prints out without reason and with extraField.

I also tried:

```
Const endpoint = <GenericApiEndpoint>req.body;
```

…but Javascript doesn’t care about that either.

Does anybody know of a simple way to validate the shape of objects in Javascript?

Comment: There are plenty ways to validate data, and I'd say that any system where you want data to persist and match a specific model, you would want some kind of field validation. ORM's usually do this but you could also use a library such as https://validatejs.org or similar. By the way, that doesn't look like javascript. Is it typescript?

Comment: Yes, it's typescript. But it's at runtime when I need the shapes validated. I'll check out validatejs.org and get back to you on whether it meets my needs or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty ways to validate data, and I'd say that any system where you want data to persist and match a specific model, you would want some kind of field validation. ORM's usually do this but you could also use a library such as:

- https://validatejs.org (for pure field validation)
- https://github.com/hapijs/joi (for creating schemas + validation)
- https://json-schema.org/ (A standard for creating schemas. Can be used with validation libraries such as https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv)

Basically the bottom line is that if you want to validate objects to make sure they fit a specific shape (model/schema), you will have to define that shape beforehand.

Comment: Any full Vanilla JS solution ?

Comment: @Emidomenge how do you define vanilla js? These libraries are written in javascript. If you want to achieve the same thing without using a library, you'd basically have to write the same thing as those libraries do.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a homemade (ideally simple) javascript function. I didn't want to use a library because of the bundle size. But finally, I had no choice. I use it and it's easy to use though

Answer (score 0):

#### use [**Zod**](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) to validate your data

```
import { z } from "zod";

// creating a schema for strings
const mySchema = z.string();

// parsing
mySchema.parse("tuna"); // => "tuna"
mySchema.parse(12); // => throws ZodError
```

you can make it as strict as you need it to be:

```
const mySchema = z.object({
  id: z.number().positive(),
  name: z.string().min(5).max(50),
  description: z.string().min(5).max(500).optional(),
  contact: z.object({
    url: z.string().url(),
    email: z.string().email(),
  }),
})
```